# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol jpeg_std_error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, linker, lib

When I use jpeglib open source codes,the following errors emerged,though I have imported **libjpeg.lib** in Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol jpeg_std_error
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol jpeg_CreateDecompress
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol jpeg_stdio_src
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol jpeg_read_header
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol jpeg_start_decompress
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol jpeg_read_scanlines
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol jpeg_finish_decompress
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol jpeg_destroy_decompress
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol jpeg_destroy
```

Comment: This is either a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12573818#12573818 or otherwise unclear how it differs

Comment: However，your refered answer hasn't addressed my problem, and I still haven't found where my problem is and how to solve it.

Comment: I am now having this problem.